# Using gdal_translate to generate large raster from tile service?

Tags: gdal-translate

I'm calling gdal_translate from the windows command line. My objective is to obtain a large geotiff, of a predefined region, from a Tiled Map Service (TMS) hosted at the University of Wisconsin.

When I run the following, I get a world map. My desire is to get an area of the Atlantic ocean off of the US east coast. (see example)

My GDAL_Translate command is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL>gdal_translate -of GTiff -outsize 2000 2300 D:\gdal_
example\ssec.xml D:\gdal_example\ssec.tif
```

My SSEC.xml is:

```
<GDAL_WMS>
<Service name="TMS">
<ServerUrl>http://realearth.ssec.wisc.edu/proxy/image.php?products=GLOBALnpptc&amp;x={x}&amp;y={y}&amp;z={z}&amp;time=2015-10-01%2012:00:00&amp;debug=false</ServerUrl>
</Service>
<DataWindow>
<UpperLeftX>-3294.54</UpperLeftX>  <!-- -85 -->
<UpperLeftY>589.29</UpperLeftY>    <!--  45 -->
<LowerRightX>3583.25</LowerRightX> <!-- -65 -->
<LowerRightY>5267.52</LowerRightY> <!--  22 -->
<TileLevel>20</TileLevel>
<TileCountX>1</TileCountX>
<TileCountY>1</TileCountY>
<YOrigin>top</YOrigin>
</DataWindow>
<Projection>EPSG:900913</Projection>
<BlockSizeX>256</BlockSizeX>
<BlockSizeY>256</BlockSizeY>
<BandsCount>3</BandsCount>
<MaxConnections>5</MaxConnections>
<Cache/>
</GDAL_WMS>
```

Desired output should resemble:

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Read gdal_translate manual where it handles -projwin.